# Как сделать поиск в MVC Web API?

Tags: c#, ajax, веб-программирование, api, mvc

```
 <div id="search">
    <label>Поиск:</label><input type="text" id="textSearch" />
    <button id="beginSearch">Поиск</button>
</div>
```

Есть такая простая поле-кнопко форма, куда вбиваешь жанр фильма, а он выдает тебе перечень фильмов, где есть такой жанр.

```
function Search() {

        var query = $(#"textSearch").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/api/values/',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                //тут должно что то быть
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
    }
```

На C#

```
public IEnumerable<Genre> GetCustomSearch(string genre)
    {
        return db.Genres.Where(p => p.Genres.Contains(genre));
    }
```

Сюда я написал запрос, который по идее и должен выводить список фильмов.
Но как это теперь правильно доделать и вывести? 
Выводить планирую в поля ниже.

```
<label>Фильм: </label></td><td><input type="text" id="film" /></td>
<label>Жанры: </label></td><td><input type="text" id="genres" /></td>
```

Если что то нужно досказать - пишите.Только начал знакомство с Web API.

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: можно в success переберать `data.forEach(elem => ...)` и уже внутри средствами jquery вставлять в какой-нибудь контейнер разметку, см. сюда https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: для более детальной реализации success, можешь скинуть вывод `console.log(data)` внутри `success`